# Mybatisplus integrates the sqlite3 database and uses the selectPage method to perform page wise queries，but can not search the total of data

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, mybatis-plus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7PYz.png)
Mybatisplus integrates the sqlite3 database and uses the selectPage method to perform page wise queries，but can not search the total of data

When I used MySQL before, there was no problem writing it this way, so I'm not sure if it's a problem with integrating SQLite

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry it was my negligence, not SQLite's reason, it turned out to be just my integration of MybatisPlus, I forgot to configure the paging plugin, the configuration is as follows, but different versions may be different, you can go to see the official website:

```html
  @Bean
    public MybatisPlusInterceptor mybatisPlusInterceptor() {
        MybatisPlusInterceptor interceptor = new MybatisPlusInterceptor();
        //  如果有多数据源可以不配具体类型 否则都建议配上具体的DbType
        interceptor.addInnerInterceptor(new PaginationInnerInterceptor(DbType.SQLITE));
        return interceptor;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!